# Keeping AWS API Gateway-Rest APIs on Sync for multi-region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-rest-api

In our  project we are using 2 regions (Oregon, N.virginia) one for **Production** and other for **DR**(Disaster recovery) site, we have the same **Rest APIs** over both regions, but the overhead arives when we have any update for the APIs we need to update on both sites.
Is there any method for synchronizing both APIs in different regions.

Currently, We are exporting the Rest APIs in JSON format and importing to other region on a timely basis.
I want to know if there any way to automate this process or other way for syncing both APIs.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to write a script of CLI commands to do this whole export and import procedure. That way you minimize manual work and standardize it. I will encounter this same problem in production after a awhile.

Comment: Iam not sure howwe script these, maybe can we run a lamda funtion to run CLI commands and schedule to trigger the function using EventBridge.

Comment: Atm I use Powershell for scripting. There is still problems to be solved so I'm not sure this will be the final solution.